# Rails show info after submit in same page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, forms

i want to show some values after click in form submit but in the same page and without refresh.

in my form

```rb
<%= simple_form_for :search, :url => url_for(:controller => "reports", :action => "search"), 
 :method => "get", :remote => true,:format => :js, 
 html: {id: "date_range", :"data-type" => "json"} do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :start_date, wrapper: :ranged_datetime,input_html: {id: "datetimepicker6"}, :label => "Fecha Inicio" %>
<%= f.input :end_date, wrapper: :ranged_datetime, input_html: {id: "datetimepicker7"} , :label => "Fecha Final" %>
 <%= f.submit 'Buscar', :class => "btn btn-success btn-lg" %>
<% end %>


<div class="datos">
<%= render :partial => 'reports/shared/sale_by_date' %>
</div>
```

and in my sale_by_date.html.erb

```rb
<% unless @sales.nil? %>
    <% @sales.each do |sale| %>
      <tr class="<%= sale.remaining_balance == 0.00 && !sale.total_amount.blank? ? 'success' : '' %>">
        <td><%= sale.sale_by_vet %></td>
        <td><%= sale.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p")  %></td>
        <td><%= sale.customer.blank? ? '-' : sale.customer.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency sale.total_amount %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency sale.tax %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency sale.paid_total %></td>
        <td><%= sale.remaining_balance == 0.00 && sale.payments.count > 0 ? "Pagado" : "#{number_to_currency sale.remaining_balance}" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Mostrar', edit_sale_path(sale) %> | <%= link_to 'Eliminar', sale, method: :delete, data: { confirm: '¿Esta seguro?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

create.js.erb

```rb
$('.datos').html("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'reports/shared/_sale_by_date.html.erb') %>");
```

and in my controller

```rb
def search
    start_date = params[:search][:start_date]
    end_date = params[:search][:end_date]
    @sales = Sale.where(:created_at => start_date..end_date)
    respond_to do |format|
       format.js { ajax_refresh }
    end
end

def ajax_refresh
  return render(:file => 'reports/create.js.erb')
end
```

but when i click in submit form, nothing happens.

console info.

```rb
Started GET "/reports/search?  utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bstart_date%5D=01%2F01%2F2015&search%5Bend_date%5D=06%2F03% 2F2015&commit=Buscar" for ::1 at 2015-06-03 10:00:44 -0500
Started GET "/reports/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bstart_date%5D=01%2F01%2F2015&search%5Bend_date%5D=06%2F03%2F2015&commit=Buscar" for ::1 at 2015-06-03 10:00:44 -0500
Processing by ReportsController#search as JSON
Processing by ReportsController#search as JSON
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>{"start_date"=>"01/01/2015",     "end_date"=>"06/03/2015"}, "commit"=>"Buscar"}
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>{"start_date"=>"01/01/2015", "end_date"=>"06/03/2015"}, "commit"=>"Buscar"}
[query values]
Rendered reports/shared/_sale_by_date.html.erb (65.5ms)
Rendered reports/shared/_sale_by_date.html.erb (65.5ms)
Rendered reports/create.js.erb (67.5ms)
Rendered reports/create.js.erb (67.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 80ms (Views: 56.8ms | ActiveRecord: 16.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 80ms (Views: 56.8ms | ActiveRecord: 16.0ms)
```

it's my first time asking, thanks !!

Comment: Based on your server log, everything seems to be working correctly, though everything appearing twice is a bit odd. Could you add a `console.log("Test");` or `alert("Test");` to your `create.js.erb` and see if that runs?

Comment: Have you checked for JavaScript errors? Everything seems okay otherwise.

Comment: `Rendered reports/create.js.erb (67.5ms)` you sure nothing happens?  Looks like you want `render partial` not `render file` in `create.js.erb`

Comment: @Clark adding `alert("Test");` or `console.log("Test");` still doing nothing.

Comment: That would suggest your `create.js.erb` is not being executed. My first thought on why is `Processing by ReportsController#search as JSON` specifically `as JSON` Comparing to a similar idea in an app I've made it's always `as JS` My suggestion is to rename `create.js.erb` to `search.js.erb` and remove your `respond_to` block from `search`

Comment: Actually, try removing `:"data-type" => "json"` from your `form_for` first.

Comment: @Clark removing `:"data-type" => "json"`  and changing the name of  js.erb solve the problem!. Many thanks !  :)

Comment: That's great to hear, I'll put that in an answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby will automatically look for a `.js.erb` of the same name when you send an AJAX request. So you can rename your `create.js.erb` to `search.js.erb` and remove your `respond_to` block. Additionally the `:"data-type" => "json"` may be causing the response to be interpreted as JSON instead of JS, and as a result it is not executed.